# select dropdown if first item not selected jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some dropdowns in page. The first item of all dropdowns is the optional value `"--Select value--"` and it's selected by default. I want to select all dropdowns where selected item value not equal  `"--Select value--"`

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("select").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() != "--Select value--";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with select selector to get all the selects with selected value is not `"--Select value--"`

```
$('select').filter(function(){
   return $(this).val() != "--Select value--";
});
```